# Ada structure member aliases

Tags: syntax, structure, ada

So I have a (geometric) vector type in Ada; it's a record with members `x`, `y` and `z`.

Under some circumstances I'm going to want to store colour triplets in this, like GLSL does. The red value will go in `x`, the green value in `y` and the  blue value in `z`. So it would be really convenient --- and make my code simpler, shorter, easier to understand and therefore more maintainable --- if I could use `r`, `g` and `b` as interchangeable aliases for `x`, `y`  and `z` (again, like GLSL does).

Can this be done?

If it were a tagged type, then I could define methods which use `Implicit_Dereference` to return a reference to the `x`, `y` and `z` members; these would be seamlessly interchangeable with real structure members. Unfortunately for implementation reasons I can't do this --- this has to interoperate with C and has to have a particular structure layout which precludes tagging. And AFAICT method syntax only works on tagged types (which is an odd limitation).

Suggestions?

Comment: I know this works for functions and packages, but how do I make it work for structural members?

Comment: Do the geometric vectors share the same data space as the colour triplets on the Ada side? or is it the C side that has a function which sometimes takes one kind, sometimes the other (presumably with another parameter to say which is meant)? or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use the [`Unchecked_Union`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3-3.html) aspect, though there are a lot of restrictions. Most of them are probably not a problem, since you want to be C-interoperable. For example,

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Aliasing_Components is
   type Vector (Colours : Boolean := False) is record
      case Colours is
         when False =>
            X, Y, Z : Integer;
         when True =>
            R, G, B : Integer;
      end case;
   end record
     with Unchecked_Union;
   V : Vector;
begin
   V := (Colours => False, X => 42, Y => 137, Z => 2014);
   Put_Line (Integer'Image (V.R));
end Aliasing_Components;
```

Comment: This _almost_ works --- the only problem is that structure literals require me to specify a value for `Colours`, and I have a zillion of them in my program I now don't want to change. It's the best solution I've found, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use subprograms to do this?

```
-- In Parent-Package
Type Geometric_Vector is
  X, Y, Z : Natural;
end record;

-- In child-package
Function R( Input : Geometric_Vector ) Return Natural is (input.R);
Function G( Input : Geometric_Vector ) Return Natural is (input.G);
Function B( Input : Geometric_Vector ) Return Natural is (input.B);
Procedure R( Object : in out Geometric_Vector; Value : Natural );
Procedure G( Object : in out Geometric_Vector; Value : Natural );
Procedure B( Object : in out Geometric_Vector; Value : Natural );

-- Child-package implementations:
Procedure R( Object : in out Geometric_Vector; Value : Natural ) is
begin
  Object.R:= Value;
end R;

Procedure G( Object : in out Geometric_Vector; Value : Natural ) is
begin
  Object.G:= Value;
end G;

Procedure B( Object : in out Geometric_Vector; Value : Natural ) is
begin
  Object.G:= Value;
end B;
```

Comment: This is more or less what I'm currently doing (although I'm using reference types to avoid needing both setters and getters). The problem with this approach is that it requires `R(v)` rather than `v.r`, which is very clunky. If I could use method-syntax calls on untagged types, of course, this would be ideal. (Not that I'm bitter, or anything.)

Comment: Am I missing something?  How does `Object.R := Value` ever compile, since `Geometric_Vector` does not have a member named `R` (and you certainly can't put a function call on the left side of `:=`)?  Or is this just a typo?

Comment: You _can_ put a function call of the left side of `:=` --- if the function returns a reference type (that is, an value whose type has `Implicit_Dereference` set and all the other rather unobvious requirements that make it work). The value will then act like a restricted scope access but with implicit dereferencing when you try to it. This is how, e.g., `container(7) := object` works. Getting `Object.R := Value` syntax then requires `Object` to be a tagged type so that method syntax function calls are enabled --- `R` is just a function with a single `in out Object_Type` parameter.